# Load only files required for runtime

Tags: php, composer-php

When you load libraries with `composer require`  you get the full package:

```
vendor/
    autoload.php
    example-author/
        example-library/
            docs/
                (5 MB of HTML and pictures)
            samples/
                (10 MB of sample data)
            test/
                (150 files)
            src/
                Foo.php (20 KB)
                Exception.php (1 KB)
```

If you only want to use the library (versus contributing to its codebase) that means deploying complete directory trees you don't need at all.

**Is that the way it's meant to be?**

I'd prefer a set-up that's closer to pre-composer age, e.g.:

```
vendor/
    autoload.php
    example-author/
        example-library/
            Foo.php
            Exception.php
```

... as long as it's a supported scenario.

Comment: Do you want to automatically omit the directories you don't need *after* `composer require` or are you after not even fetching the docs / test / unneeded directories? There's [this issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1750) where guys agreed upon not fetching docs. I use `post-install` hook in `composer.json` to perform cleanup tasks where I remove stuff that I don't need. I don't know if this info will be useful to you, so I'm posting as a comment, maybe someone else has a better solution so I'll stick around to check what's posted by others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you download from `dist` and not from `source`.

> **Dist:** The dist is a packaged version of the package data. Usually a released version, usually a stable release.
>
> **Source:** The source is used for development. This will usually originate from a source code repository, such as git. You can fetch
>   this when you want to modify the downloaded package.
>
> Packages can supply either of these, or even both. Depending on
>   certain factors, such as user-supplied options and stability of the
>   package, one will be preferred.

If the packages are configured properly then they should not have the `tests` and `docs` included in the `dist`. You can easily check this in the sources of the packages at github. There should be a `.gitattributes` file where some files are excluded for the `dist` archive like this one:

```
/tests export-ignore
/docs export-ignore
.gitattributes export-ignore
.gitignore export-ignore
.gitmodules export-ignore
.travis.yml export-ignore
build.properties export-ignore
build.xml export-ignore
phpunit.xml.dist export-ignore
run-all.sh export-ignore
composer.lock export-ignore
```

This is explained in the [Exporting Your Repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Exporting-Your-Repository) chapter of the Git documentation.

If there is no `.gitattributes` in the sources then you will have to ask the author of that package to include one or make a pull request yourself.

#### Composer's default

When your composer is in default configuration to use `stable` packages and the preferred install is `dist`.

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

Then composer downloads a zip file from github, which was created with the filters defined in `.gitattributes`.

#### Make composer download from dist

If you like to have the `dist` archive you have two options.

1. Make the `"preferred-install": "dist"`
2. Use the `--prefer-dist` option on `composer update`

Both of them make composer to use `dist` for *all* packages.
If you like to have only the sources of `example-author/example-library` instead of the `dist` of all packages then use:

```
composer update example-author/example-library --prefer-dist
```

#### Note

You will have to delete the package folder (you like to update from `dist`) in your `/vendor` folder if it already exists to get it reinstalled. Otherwise it will stick to the already downloaded version.

Comment: Glad to see the feature exists and works exactly the way I described it. Probably not many package owners know/care about this and that's why I hadn't noticed myself even though it's the default option. Thank you for a superb answer.

Comment: BTW, if I understood correctly the `.gitattributes` information applies to automatic release generation using git and Composer does not really force that. Dist installation should work even if all you have is a manually generated ZIP file, as long as the package is properly configured in Packagist.

Comment: I guess the ZIP file comes from the auto generated ZIP from github so adding a `.gitattributes` always works out of the box I think. I know many packages don't have a `.gitattributes` included, but it takes you about 2 min to send a pull request and most devs will accept it, if you explain it with 2 or 3 sentences.

Comment: I just meant that, since Composer packages do not necessarily need to be hosted at github (or even use git), that bit information only applies to git. You can e.g. develop a library with Subversion and publish a ZIP file you generate with Phing.